# Преобразование массива double к массиву complex и выполнение БПФ

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Поясните, пожалуйста, у меня имеется массив double полученный с wav-файла, как теперь его преобразовать в массив complex?

Я планирую использовать этот код для быстрого преобразования Фурье:

```
private static Complex w(int k, int N)
{
    if (k % N == 0) return 1;
    double arg = -2 * Math.PI * k / N;
    return new Complex(Math.Cos(arg), Math.Sin(arg));
}

public static Complex[] fft(Complex[] x)
{
    Complex[] X;
    int N = x.Length;
    if (N == 2)
    {
        X = new Complex[2];
        X[0] = x[0] + x[1];
        X[1] = x[0] - x[1];
    }
    else
    {
        Complex[] x_even = new Complex[N / 2];
        Complex[] x_odd = new Complex[N / 2];
        for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
        {
            x_even[i] = x[2 * i];
            x_odd[i] = x[2 * i + 1];
        }
        Complex[] X_even = fft(x_even);
        Complex[] X_odd = fft(x_odd);
        X = new Complex[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N / 2; i++)
        {
            X[i] = X_even[i] + w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
            X[i + N / 2] = X_even[i] - w(i, N) * X_odd[i];
        }
    }
    return X;
}
```

Который выложен на википедии, как я понял, если я планирую предварительно преобразовать массив double в массив complex, то метод w не нужен?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не скажу конкретно про C#, но скажу про БПФ.

> если я планирую предварительно преобразовать массив double в массив complex

БПФ работает на комплексном буфере. Придется преобразовать. Выбора нет.

> то метод w не нужен?

Метод w это комплексная экспонента, которая используется в БПФ в любом случае. Здесь тоже нет выбора.

Преобразование действительного в комплексное это просто установка реальной части в нужное значение, а мнимой в 0.

Comment: понял, спасибо.

Comment: А подскажите этот момент, как установить реальную и мнимую часть, я этот момент не совсем пойму. Понял, что как говорили ранее в реальной части будут значения массива double, а мнимая часть будет равна нулю. Тут будет код, который представлен ниже?

Comment: @Andrey273, в вашем примере из Википедии это, вроде, делается так: x_even[i] = x[2 * i]; и [описание в msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.numerics.complex(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Ну например так:

```
var complexArray = doubleArray.Select(d => (Complex)d).ToArray();
```

(Я не уверен в физическом смысле преобразования, по какой именно формуле преобразовывать, вы должны знать лучше.)